# Migrate to Spring Data JPA from Synyx Hades

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to migrate from Hades to Spring Data JPA (I know, it's late). However, when I use the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation in my configuration to enable it, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Environment must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112) ~[spring-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.<init>(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:50) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.java:74) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:74) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:395) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:131) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:401) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:140) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:282) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461) ~[spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_55]
```

As I'm not the most experienced Spring user I have no idea where to even begin to debug this and Google didn't return anything. If I explicitly autowire an `Environment` somewhere, I get one so I don't know why it would be null here.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: For starters fix your dependencies, you are mixing spring 3.2.3 and 3.2.6 jars. Never mix versions of jars.

Comment: can you add the code of Environment?

Comment: @paul Environment is a [Spring class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java) ;-).

Comment: Never used before, in that case maybe you can take a look to this ticket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070964/spring-3-1-configuration-environment-not-injected

Comment: Are you willing to try out Spring 3.2.9? There is a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11744) that might be the reason for your exception. And, of course, as @M.Deinum said - don't mix versions.

Comment: Ah yes. Version 3.2.6 seems to come from Spring Data. I'll see tomorrow whether upgrading Spring helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the fix is rather trivial: After fixing the version of all Spring components to 3.2.9, everything works as it should.

I'm fairly sure it's due to [Bug SPR-11744](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11744) (thanks to [Andrei Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3498062/andrei-stefan) in the comments to the question).